# Removing ads in a live stream with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, stream, ads

I am trying to remove ads from a live stream with jQuery. (I know this has been asked before, but it seems to be different in this case than in the other cases when this question has been asked some time ago.) In detail:

The iframe part of my page looks like this:

```
<iframe id="iframe" width="100%" height="360" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="yes" src="https://daddyhd.com/embed/stream-61.php"></iframe>
```

The PHP script (stream-61.php) loads the actual live stream (in a second iframe with id #thatframe). The problem is that the PHP script also loads a bunch of ads and scripts that continually load more ads. Plus, the second iframe can only be accessed from the server where is it stored (X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN is set), so I cannot load it direct on my page.

After looking at the resulting HTML code from stream-61.php, I tried to use jQuery to .remove() all tags except the second iframe (#thatframe) with the actual live stream. It works on my computer, when I make up two iframes with my own div and script tags. But it does not work with the URL I gave above.

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think» you could use `<script>$(document).ready(function(){ $('#thatframe').load("https://example.com/stream-61.php");  });</script>` with jQuery, instead of iFrame. my english is not good. sorry :)

Comment: but Before that you should insert `<div id="thatframe"></div>` in body.

Comment: After, you can use `$('.myDiv').remove();`

Comment: No, it is not. Did you try it with the URL I gave?